# How can I generate a random time per day with php?

Tags: php, datetime, random

I want to generate one random time within a 24 hour period using php. Here is what I have so far:

```
srand(mktime(0, 0, 0));
$time = rand( 0, time() );
echo date("H:i", $time);
```

It seemed to work at first but after a couple hours the time changed slightly. I got 16:41 first and then it jumped to 16:47 or something near that. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you call that whole set of code each time? If you do surely the rand function is generating a new time each time it goes through the code?

Answer (score 9):

How about simply do this,

```
echo rand(0,23).":".str_pad(rand(0,59), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

more better with *[mt_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)*,

```
echo mt_rand(0,23).":".str_pad(mt_rand(0,59), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.org/MvPpvzX3)**.

Answer (score 4):

Or should you need a more object-oriented approach, that's three lines:

```
$randDate = new DateTime();
$randDate->setTime(mt_rand(0, 23), mt_rand(0, 59));
echo $randDate->format('Y-m-d H:i');  // or whatever format you need
```

I would recommend to use mt_rand() over random_int(), because you don't necessarily need the cryptographic random ints in this case - mt_rand() is faster

Answer (score 0):

Your code will generate every time a new random time when your web page get loaded. You should create a cookie for one day. It will destroy automatically after one day. You should change your code like

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["one_day_cookie"])){
 srand(mktime(0, 0, 0));
 $time = rand( 0, time() );
 setcookie("one_day_cookie", $time, time()+(3600*24*1));  /* expire in 1 day */

}else{
 $time = $_COOKIE["one_day_cookie"];
}

echo date("H:i", $time);
```

Comment: Thank you for your work Vineet. I believe the above will be per visiter correct so as soon as someone visits the webpage the 24 hours will begin, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$unix_start = strtotime("2017-10-10 12:25:16");
$unix_end = strtotime("2017-10-11 11:48:06");
$diff = $unix_end - $unix_start ;
$rndtime =  $unix_start + mt_rand(0,$diff);
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$rndtime);
```

and another version for only hour and minute

```
$unix_start = strtotime("2017-10-10 12:25:16");
$unix_end = strtotime("2017-10-10 12:48:06");
$diff = $unix_end - $unix_start;
$rndtime =  $unix_start + mt_rand(0,$diff);
echo date("H:i",$rndtime);
```

Start time always must be low end time.